# Is there a way to move object much faster on linerenderer line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            objectToMove.transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        objectToMove.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(objectToMove.transform.position,
                                                pos[index],
                                                speed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (objectToMove.transform.position == pos[index])
        {
            index += 1;
        }

        if (index == pos.Length)
            index = 0;
    }
}
```

Even if I'm setting the speed value to 1000 or even to 10000 the speed is faster but not so fast or not very fast.

There are 1157 position in the variable array positions. So it's a bit a problem to move fast no so many positions and in other cases there might be 5000 positions or more depending on the linerenderer line length.

but I saw in some youtube demos cars and objects moving fast very fast on curved lines or very long length lines.

Comment: How fast you can move looks like it is determined by how close together your points are. Even if you're moving really fast, the most you could move would be from one point to another in one update cycle. There's no logic to say, for example, if you move at 100 miles per update and your distance between points is 1 mile, to continue to the next points until the 100 miles has been traveled. Thus, I think that could be affecting things. It doesn't matter how fast your speed is if you're limiting the number of stops (`pos`) per frame.

Comment: @ps2goat and if I jump over some positions ? I mean if there are 1000 positions but I will move only over each 10 positions index for example start at position index 0 then jump to index 10 then to 20....1000 will it keep the smoothness of the curved line effect movement and also will be faster ? Or it will looks like the object is jumping from place to place ?

Comment: @ps2goat Then by logic how in games you make a plane or car or spaceship moving in waypoints including curved waypoints in long areas tracks ? For example endless track game movement or a plane that move in the sky automatic ?

Comment: It depends on the scale you're working with. If you have a working project sample that I can look at, I can have better context. Based on what the user sees, the object may not hit every point. But the object will somewhat follow the path. You wouldn't want to go full speed around corners for things like trains on tracks, but it may not be as noticeable for things like planes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out how much distance to move in the current frame, then loop through points until you've traveled that distance:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLine : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public GameObject objectToMove;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            objectToMove.transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = objectToMove.transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime; 

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);

            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                index = (index + 1) % pos.Length;
            }
            else 
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        objectToMove.transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I want it to move backward on the track when it's getting to the last waypoint what should I change in the code ? Now it's getting to the last waypoint and then moving to the first one but I want it to move like in reverse to the first one and then to move forward again. The curved line is built from 5 cubes can be more but now it's 5 cubes that a curved line is connected between each two cubes. It can be 10 cubes or 2 cubes then I move one of the cubes and it's making the curved line.  The question is how can I make it go back as reverse when it's getting to the end ?

Comment: Because now it's not depending on the cubes as waypoints but on the positions that's why I'm not sure as to make it move at reverse when it's getting to the end and then move forward again when it's getting to the start.

Comment: change `index = (index + 1) % pos.Length;` to appropriate logic for changing the index. The question didn't mention any of this so I will avoid cluttering the answer with all possible ways of changing the index...