# How can I make the transform rotating smooth facing each waypoint?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public float rotSpeed;
    public bool random = false;
    public int currentCurvedLinePointIndex;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numofposbetweenpoints;
    private bool getPositions = false;
    int randomIndex;
    int curvedPointsIndex;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();

        if (curvedLinePoints != null && curvedLinePoints.Count > 0)
        {
            transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;
        }

        if (random)
            GetNewRandomIndex();
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (lineRenderer.positionCount > 0 && getPositions == false)
        {
            pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();
            numofposbetweenpoints = pos.Length / curvedLinePoints.Count;

            if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
            {
                transform.position = pos[index];
            }

            getPositions = true;
        }

        if (go == true && lineRenderer.positionCount > 0)
        {
            Move();

            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, curvedLinePoints[c].transform.localRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
        }

        var dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, curvedLinePoints[curvedPointsIndex].transform.position);
        if (dist < 0.1f)
        {
            if (curvedPointsIndex < curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                curvedPointsIndex++;

            currentCurvedLinePointIndex = curvedPointsIndex;
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int c = 1;
    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;

            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);

            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;
                            
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne)
                    {
                        index--;

                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;
                            
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

In the Update this line rotate the transform :

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, curvedLinePoints[c].transform.localRotation, Time.deltaTime * rotSpeed);
```

but first it should not be with the 'c' int variable because the calculation is wrong there are 30 Cubes in the List curvedLinePoints. but when calculating with the numofposbetweenpoints variable there are only 20 in the numofposbetweenpoints and then when increasing the 'c' variable it will be increasing only by  20 and not 30 but maybe I'm wrong at this part.

second it's not rotating at all.

In the screenshot the Platform is the object that move. The Cubes that create stairs are the curvedLinePoints List.

The Platform is moving along the positions of LineRenderer positions between the cubes but I want that the Platform will rotate facing the Cubes in the curvedLinePoints List and not the LineRenderer positions!

[image: Platform green axis facing forward]

On the array pos there are 610 positions but I want the transform to rotate facing each curvedLinePoint.

In my opinion I think when the transform the Platform is reaching up the last position and then start moving back down the platform should rotate the green axis should face down because the platform is moving down now so it should be looking at the curvedLinePoints that are on the way down direction but the platform keep looking forward up and never rotating to the direction it's moving.

When the platform reach/passed the last curvedLinePoint rotate back facing the other curvedLinePoints I think this is how it should be like by logic.

Comment: Glad to see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64561989/1092820) still helping people. How is the game supposed to know which rotational waypoint to use for each position along your move trajectory? You need some way of telling the code how fast to turn between each waypoint. I'm guessing it's not correct to assume the platform has a constant rotational speed. The easiest way would be to just have the same number of directional waypoints as positional waypoints and it interpolates between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the same number of rotational waypoints as positional waypoints, you could determine the rotation had at each positional waypoint then interpolate between them. Only, keep track of the forward directions and finally use `LookRotation` to convert to a rotation:

```
void Move()
{
    Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
    Vector3 newDir = transform.forward;

    float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

    bool stillTraveling = true;
    while (stillTraveling)
    {
        Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
        Vector3 oldDir = newDir;

        float distanceToNext = Vector3.Distance(oldPos, pos[index]);

        newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);

        newDir = curvedLinePoints[index] - pos[index];
        newDir.z = 0; // look directly ahead

        if ( distanceToNext >= distanceToTravel)
        {  
            // How far from oldPos tonewPos 
            float t = Mathf.InverseLerp(0, distanceToNext, distanceToTravel); 
            newDir = Vector3.Slerp(oldDir, newDir, t);
        }

        distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(oldPos, newPos);
        if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
        {
            // when you hit a waypoint:
            if (goForward)
            {
                bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                if (!atLastOne)
                {
                    index++;
                    counter++;
                    if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                    {
                        c++;
                        
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                    {
                        c = 0;
                    }
                }
                else { index--; goForward = false; }
            }
            else
            { // going backwards:
                bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                if (!atFirstOne)
                {
                    index--;

                    counter++;
                    if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                    {
                        c++;
                        
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                    if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                    {
                        c = 0;
                    }
                }
                else { index++; goForward = true; }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            stillTraveling = false;
        }
    }
    transform.position = newPos;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(newDir);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting exception in the editor on this line : newDir = curvedLinePoints[index].transform.position - pos[index]; out of range.  There are 30 curvedLinePoints and 601 pos the transform the platform should and moving between the pos array 601 positions but should only rotating facing the curvedLinePoints the index is increasing according to the pos number 601

Comment: @user1196715 The answer says you need to have the same number of position waypoints as you do direction waypoints. Each position waypoint should have a direction waypoint.